# Replace one dataframe column value with another's value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two dataframes (Scala Spark) A and B. When `A("id") == B("a_id")` I want to update `A("value")` to `B("value")`. Since DataFrames have to be recreated I'm assuming I have to do some joins and withColumn calls but I'm not sure how to do this. In SQL it would be a simple update call on a natural join but for some reason this seems difficult in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a left join and a `select` call would do the trick:

```
// assuming "spark" is an active SparkSession: 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// some sample data; Notice it's convenient to NAME the dataframes using .as(...)
val A = Seq((1, "a1"), (2, "a2"), (3, "a3")).toDF("id", "value").as("A")
val B = Seq((1, "b1"), (2, "b2")).toDF("a_id", "value").as("B")

// left join + coalesce to "choose" the original value if no match found:
val result = A.join(B, $"A.id" === $"B.a_id", "left")
  .select($"id", coalesce($"B.value", $"A.value") as "value")

// result:
// +---+-----+
// | id|value|
// +---+-----+
// |  1|   b1|
// |  2|   b2|
// |  3|   a3|
// +---+-----+
```

Notice that there's no real "update" here - `result` is a new DataFrame which you can use (write / count / ...) but the original DataFrames remain unchanged.

Comment: First, you can replace these with the `col` function, e.g. `col("A.id")` if they give you trouble; Second - you need that `import spark.implicits._` in every scope where you'd want to use `$`.

Comment: like the left join winds up having like a full outer join for some reason or something

Comment: This might happen if some records in A have more than one matching record in B (i.e. where A.id == B.a_id) - is that the case? If so, by what logic would you "choose" the right value from B? Try grouping B before joining so that B has _unique_ a_id values.

Comment: even if i do a left outer join on the same data frame (ie. i take A and then join with B and make C (not full outer) then take the original A and join with C on the same id for the same columns) the left outer join does not seem to work properly as i would expect it coming from a sql background. it seems like it does a full outer each time

Comment: In the example I supplied above you can see left join working as expected. You'd have to present specific code and specific data, preferably as a separate post - I won't be able to help via comments without more info.